# Does my Netbook have enough performance to run Eclipse?

Tags: performance, netbook, eclipse

I want to buy a netbook. It's a Samsung N143 (here is the [specification](http://www.ultra-laptops.com/laptops/manufacturers/pos/samsung_n143)).

It is not the most powerful netbook, so I am very worried about one thing:

Can I work normally with Eclipse IDE, yes or no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to use Eclipse IDE with these specifications but don't expect to have great performance. It will depend on the size of the project you are working with. I'd consider upgrading to 2 Gb of RAM to help.

But the most important reason why I would not use such a netbook for Eclipse development is the small screen size. I think that such a small screen resolution will make it difficult to use a software in which you need to use multiple panel at once. It will probably leave little room for the code window. For example, I use Eclipse from time to time on my laptop which has a 1280*800 resolution and on these moments I REALLY miss my 1080p monitor.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the screen size comment?

Comment: I think that such a small screen resolution will make it difficult to use a software in which you need to use multiple panel at once. It will probably leave little room for the code window. For example, I use Eclipse from time to time on my laptop which has a 1280*800 resolution and on these moments I REALLY miss my 1080p monitor.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the kind of work you'd do with it. If you're going to develop GUI-heavy apps, the screen is *far* too small for instance.